# How do I dynamically create a Firebase Storage reference based on previous reference value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, url, firebase-storage

Here's a brief overview of the process that I need help with:

1. Client uploads images to Firebase Storage at users/displayName/uid/ - this step is clear and done. No help needed on this one.
2. Then, client presses "request a quote" button which saves the URLs of the images (the ones that were uploaded to Storage in step 1) to Firebase Firestore - this step is clear and done. No help needed on this one.
3. After the URLs are saved to the Firestore, I want those images from Step 1 to be moved within the same bucket of the Storage to users/displayName/uid/order1. So, basically, from users/displayName/uid/ to users/displayName/uid/order1. - I need help with writing out the right Javascript code for this action. I tried the code snippet from below but it does not seem to work, not sure what is wrong.
4. At some point in the future, the same client will need to upload more images thus repeating the first 3 steps above. However, on the 3rd step, I will need his images to be moved from users/displayName/uid/ to users/displayName/uid/order2. The problem lies in me not knowing how to render the last part of the directory as order2 and not the same order1 as in the 3rd step. The number after "order" will basically need to increase every time the client repeats the steps. I have no idea of how to write out the right code for this. Please help.

If it helps, here are my functions that upload images to Firebase Storage and Firebase Firestore:

```
// Upload to Storage

    handleUpload = () => {

        this.state.files.forEach((file) => {
            const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}/${file.name}`);
            var task = storageRef.put(file)


            // Progress

            task.on("state_changed", snapshot => {

                const progress = Math.round(
                    (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                );
                this.setState({ progress });
            },


                // Error

                error => {
                    console.log(error);
                },


                // Additional function to update state with all files uploaded

                () => {
                    firebase.storage()
                        .ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}`)
                        .child(file.name)
                        .getDownloadURL()
                        .then(url => {
                            this.setState(state => {
                                const urls = [...state.urls, url];
                                return {
                                    urls
                                };
                            });
                        });


                    // Empty file upload

                    this.setState({ progress: 0 })
                    this.setState({ files: [] })
                }
            );

        })


    };


// Saving to Firestore - PRESS GET A QUOTE TO ACTIVATE

    async saveToFirestore() {

        // Getting it all from storage first        
        const listRef = firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}`)

        const res = await listRef.listAll()
        const urlPromises = res.items.map((itemRef) => {
            return itemRef.getDownloadURL()
        })
        const urls = await Promise.all(urlPromises)


        // Then, we save it all to Firestore
        firebase.firestore().collection('Documents/').doc(this.state.displayName).set({
            documents: urls,
            quote: 'pending',
            name: this.state.displayName,
            email: this.state.email,
            emailVerified: this.state.emailVerified,
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            userId: this.state.uid
        })
            .then(() => {

                const listRef = firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}`)

                listRef.listAll().then((res) => {

                    console.log(res)

                    res.items.forEach(function (item) {

                        console.log(item)

                        firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}/order1/${item.name}`).put(item);
                    });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                });



                this.setState({ quote: "pending" })

                firebase.firestore().collection('Documents/').doc(this.state.displayName).get().then((doc) => {

                    if (doc.exists) {
                        doc.data().documents.forEach(url => {
                            this.setState(state => {
                                const documents = [...state.documents, url];
                                return {
                                    documents
                                };
                            });
                        })


                        this.setState({ createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate().toString() })

                    } else {
                        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                        console.log("No such document!");
                    }
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
            });

    }
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "After they upload to Storage, they perform an action that uploads those images to Firebase Firestore." Can you edit your question to show the code for that? Unless that code is not relevant to the question of course, but in that case: please also update your problem description to not need it anymore. In general, I'm having a hard time parsing your use-case because there is so much going on. The more you can reduce the scope, the more likely it is that we can help.

Comment: Is your question "how do I determine the new path of an image based on its old path and a transformation?" Or is it: "how do I determine the next available folder name through the Firebase Storage API?"

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your response. The code of how the images get uploaded to Firestore is irrelevant. No, I do not want to determine the new path based on an image’s old path because all images are first uploaded to Storage at users/userDisplayName/uid. After a certain action (client requesting a quote), they are to be moved to their respective locations as orders, order1, order2, order3 etc. My question is how do I create those new paths (order1, order2, order3 etc) dynamically or programatically for the images - users/userDisplayName/uid/order1. I will add more details above too.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Frank , I have updated the question above and added a brief overview of the process I am trying to implement. Please let me know if you can help or if you need anything else. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is *way* too long at this point, but from a quick scan it still reads like: "how do I determine the next available folder name through the Firebase Storage API?" Can you confirm?

Comment: Hey Frank, I have removed all the unnecessary information. Please read the brief summary on top. It should now be clear. I am not sure I understand your question, though. Please rephrase. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you have two parts to your question:

1. Determine the folder for the next order
2. Write all files from the root to this folder

I'll focus on the first step in this answer.

#### Determine the folder for the next order

To determine the next `order?` folder, we'll get a list of all files/folders from Storage, and then filter them to determine the highest number in there:

```
var ref = firebase.storage().ref("62849565");

ref.listAll().then(function(res) {
  // Determine the next order folder
  const orderFolders = res.prefixes.filter((folder) => folder.name.match(/^order(\d+)$/));
  let highestOrderNumber = 0;
  orderFolders.forEach((folder) => {
    const match = folder.name.match(/^order(\d+)$/);
    const number = parseInt(match[1]);
    if (number > highestOrderNumber) {
      highestOrderNumber = number;
    }
  })
  const nextOrderFolderPrefix = "order" + (highestOrderNumber+1);

  // Move the files from the root to the new folder
  res.items.forEach(function(itemRef) {
    // TODO: read file from root and write it to the next order folder
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

(Also see this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vikotak/edit?js,console) where I created/tested this code)

In the above:

1. The `res.prefixes.filter((folder) => folder.name.match(/^order(\d+)$/))` ensures we only consider folders following the `order1` naming pattern.
2. We then loop over the folders to find the highest number.
3. We them determine the path for the next folder.

---

#### Write all files from the root to the new folder

The `TODO` in this code is to move the actual file. There is no operation in Cloud Storage (or its Firebase SDK) to **move** a file. So you will have to do a sequence of read the file, write it to its new location, and removing it from its original location. I recommend searching around a bit, as I'm pretty sure this must have been asked before.

Comment: Hi Frank, wonderful, perfect code, thank you very much! The only issue that remains is the 2nd part (Write all files from the root to the new folder). I have read all the articles and could not find a code example. Only references to doc pages. I tried this code but it says it expects a file or blob in an error. Here's the code: res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {                    firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}/order`).put(itemRef)
  }); Any ideas why this does not work and what will work? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Frank, please see this question I just posted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62865814/why-does-my-code-that-attempts-to-copy-files-from-the-root-directory-of-firebase

Comment: Sure, any ideas on how to copy files from the root to a folder?

Comment: Why do you match the same RegEx twice in your code above? (folder) => folder.name.match(/^order(\d+)$/)); AND const match = folder.name.match(/^order(\d+)$/);

Comment: The first one is to find the filters that define orders, while the second one is to extract the number from it. If you want, you can refactor this to only perform one regex match, or even merge the filter and the loop, but the code will work the same.