# Why does my code that attempts to copy files from the root directory of Firebase Storage to a new folder not work?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I am trying to copy or move files from the root in Firebase Storage to a folder. More specifically, from users/displayName/uid/ to users/displayName/uid/somefolder. I have read that there is no method in the Firebase Storage API to make a copy of a file that you've already uploaded and that you will have to download the data and re-upload it. I could not find any sample codes, however. Therefore, I have written the following code to try to accomplish that but it does not work. See the error below to find out why.

Here's the code I have written:

```
const listRef = firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}`)

listRef.listAll().then((res) => {

    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {

        firebase.storage().ref(`users/${this.state.displayName}/${this.state.uid}/somefolder`).put(itemRef)
    });
}

).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

So, this code does not work and nothing happens. No folder is created. Here's the error that comes up:

```
FirebaseStorageError {code_: "storage/invalid-argument", message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_: "FirebaseError"}
code: (...)
code_: "storage/invalid-argument"
message: (...)
message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."
name: (...)
name_: "FirebaseError"
serverResponse: (...)
serverResponse_: null
__proto__: Object
```

By all appearances, the `put` method expects a file or blob and not the items that you get with the `listAll()` method.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue and move or copy a file to a folder successfully? Real code samples will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a reference `put()`.  According to the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#put), there are three different things you can pass: a Blob, an Uint8array, or an ArrayBuffer.

The problem, however, is that the javascript web client SDK doesn't give you a way of directly downloading data in any of those formats.  You're going to have to figure out how to do that yourself, perhaps by [getting a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), or offloading that work to a backend that can use a server SDK to copy data around.

Comment: Hi Doug, would admin.storage.object capture multiple files at the same time because multiple files may be uploaded at the same time? If not, then, how to make sure each file from multiple uploaded is handled. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately with an explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933402/does-admin-storage-object-contain-process-multiple-files-if-multiple-files-are-u