# Does admin.storage.object contain/process multiple files if multiple files are uploaded to Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am trying to move files into separate folders in Firebase Storage once they have been uploaded. As it turns out, you can not achieve this with the the JavaScript Web Client SDK for Storage. However, it appears that you could do so with the Admin SDK for Storage using Firebase Functions. So that is what I am trying to do. I understand that you need to first download a file into your Firebase Functions and then re-upload into a new folder in Storage.

To download a file, I need to pass its reference from the client and here is where it gets confusing to me. I am currently getting all the uploaded files in the client via the listAll() function which returns items and prefixes. I am wondering whether or not I can use either the items or the prefixes to then download the files into Firebase Functions using them (items or prefixes). Alternatively, I can pass the URLs. However, the question is, which method do I use to get and download them in Functions afterwards?

I know of admin.storage.object as explained in https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_changes. However, does it handle multiples files? In other words, the object, as I understand, is one file that is uploaded to Storage and you can use its attributes such as object.bucket or object.name to access more information. However, what if there are multiple files uploaded at the same time, does it handle them one by one? Also, if I am passing the references or URLs of the files that need to be downloaded from the client, is admin.storage.object the right choice? Because it seems to simply process all the files uploaded to Storage, instead of getting any references from the client.

Further, there is a description of how to download a file (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#example_image_transformation) which is this code: await bucket.file(filePath).download({destination: tempFilePath});
I understand that the filepath is basically the name of the file that is already in Storage (ex. /someimage). But what if there are other files with the same name? Might the wrong file be downloaded? And how do I make sure that the filepath is the file that I passed from the client?

Let me know what your thoughts are and whether or not I am heading in the right direction. If you include a code in your answer, please write it in JavaScript for the Web. Thank you.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some points that could help:

- In GCP Storage technically there are no folders, GCS [emulates](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) the directory structure by using / in the names of objects.
- When setting a cloud function [triggered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_on_changes) by a GCS object change, each object change is an event, each event triggers an invocation of the function (you might have an bucket for unprocessed files which triggers the function and have them move to a different bucket when proccesed)
- You might consider using the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#rest-rename-object) to move/copy/rename the objects without having to download them

As a side note the question is a little too broad, possibly these points could help clarify things for you.

Comment: Why do you say there are no folders in Storage when you can actually create them there? Also, I am okay with moving files to a different location or path in the directory. I just need to find out how to do it?

Isn’t there a limit to the bucket creation? I mean, what if I have hundreds or thousands of users moving objects between buckets? A user may end up having multiple (20-50) buckets as their orders. Isn’t that the wrong approach?

Comment: Please don't misunderstand the folder situation in GCP, one can certainly use folders in GCP storage but behind the scenes the folder concept doesn't exist, its just an abstraction that uses a forward slash in object names as explained in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). I am sorry but I am not quite understanding what is the actual question, I would recommend creating different posts for separate questions you may have to make easier to understand.